# ASP.NET trying to take records out of database fails

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, entity-framework

I recently started using .NET to create simple program. I have some records in database, now I need them to show up in a webpage. I've created an EF controller, and when trying to access the webpage it error says:

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser'.

on this line of code

```
 return View(db.ApplicationUsers.ToList());
```

After checking similar answers I found that I might need to delete

```
  public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

from my context, but after doing this, I'm getting lots of errors.

Any ideas??

Comment: To me, the error clearly points that  `ApplicationUsers` and `Users`, both use `WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser` and this is not supported. You can try to inherit one from another - `ApplicationUsers : Users`

Comment: Sorry, where should I do that? Also, I can't seem to find "User" using that...

Comment: Wherever you use `ApplicationUsers` replace it by `Users`, or reverse, and delete one of the properties. The error is pretty clear and there's no way to work around it.

Comment: That sounds pretty clear, but the problem is that I cant find property `Users` anywhere... After changing all `ApplicationUsers` with `Users` the error now is `The object sets 'Users' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser'.`